# google spreadsheet get/update row where column 'A' equals id

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

How can I get/update a row where column 'A' equals some id that I have?

So for example I have a row with 6 columns and want to change three of them. Do I need to get the row, edit the values and save it again in the same row or can I just overwrite the three values I want to update?

Currently I take all rows and then I look for the right id, edit this object and write all rows back to the sheet. That's way to much read and write I think.

That's how I am currently accesing the sheet:

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require("google-spreadsheet");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const creds = require("./client_secret.json");
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
const tt = promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
```

and the write all rows with with

```
for(row in rows){
    await promisify(sheet.addRow)(row);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you have?

Comment: How can I just update one row? Currently I update every row if I want to change only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment yet but if your  column *A* has a header named *ID* this will work:

At first you want to get the row where the id from the column with the name 'ID' equals your userId and then you can edit the values and save it.

```
var row = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset: 1,
        query: 'id = ' + userId      //checks where column 'id' (not case sensitive) matches userId
});

row[0].someothercolumn = "value";

promisify(row[0].save)();
```